# How do I set the default title view for my navigation controllers?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I'm writing an iOS 6 app and I want to set a title view that will show for all of my views, unless I specify otherwise. I've tried `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleView:view]` and `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleView:view]`, but neither have worked.

Note: this title view cannot be a label, it must be a button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a UINavigationController?

If so, use something like the following to set the background image and font:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                       [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:22.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"]           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If you only want to apply the changes to Navigation Bars in certain specific subclasses of UIViewController, then use something like the following:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[VCSubclassToChangeAppearance class], nil] 
setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"]
forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You can also use this method for creating exceptions to the rule e.g. set one appearance for all, except one in particular.

If you want to change the appearance of the standard buttons on the nav bar, do something like this:

```
UIImage *standardBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarButton.png"]
                                    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 8)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:standardBackgroundImage
                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

In this example, every nav bar button (that's not a back button) and is of the UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered variety, will use the image. You'll need to work on the UIEdgeInsets for your particular button image.

Comment: I need to have a button as the title view, not a label.

Comment: When you say "title view" do you actually mean UINavigationBar? It would help to clarify if I'm actually sending you down the correct path.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. The title view of each UINavigationBar.

Comment: I've modified my answer in order to show you how to change the appearance of a button on the nav bar. Again, you can use "appearanceWhenContainedIn:" if you only want to do this for specific VCs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a subview (UITextField) to your navigation bar:

```
UITextField *titleField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0, 60.0)];
titleField.text = @"a title";
titleField.center = self.navigationController.navigationBar.center;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:titleField];
```

Comment: How would I then customize it in individual view controllers?

Comment: I would do it by defining a property on the individual view controllers i.e. someViewController.titleField. Then, after creating and adding the titleField to the bar, I would set someViewController.titleField = titleField (giving the new view controller a reference to the titleField). Then push someViewController. From inside someViewController you could then access self.titleField to customize the view.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can define a global variable after that set title for each viewController by command:

   self.title = kDefaultTitle
2. If you use story board, you can set it on each viewController in Title properties at right bar
3. Final: I think you can automatically set all title of view (exclude you attack to core)

Comment: Can you elaborate on 3 please? Also, I don't just want to set a title, I want to set an actual title view.

Comment: I recommend you not attack to core, it very dangerous with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Because UIBarButtonItem of different view controllers will change the title view of the navigation bar, you can not set the title view globally. You can use @Jake approach or subclass `UIViewController` in which you can override the `setTitle` method. And use that class as the superclass of all your own view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can put any view into titleView in any **ViewController** which is wrapped in **UINavigationController** by following code.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = yourView;
```

Try this one.